# How to create square semi-log plot (axes of equal dimensions) in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create square plots (equal axes length) on semi-log scale, but I have no luck. Can any one help me with this. For log-log scale I used this function:

```
def set_aspect_ratio_log(plot, aspect_ratio):
    x_min, x_max = plot.get_xlim()
    y_min, y_max = plot.get_ylim()
    return plot.set_aspect(aspect_ratio * ((math.log10(x_max / x_min)) / (math.log10(y_max / y_min)))
```

But how do I this for semi-log plot in matplotlib.

**Update**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [12.4, 18.2, 20.3, 22.9, 27.7, 35.5, 53.9]
y = [1, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
fig.clf()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
plot.plot(x, y, linestyle = ':', marker='^', label='label')
plt.xscale('log')
plot.set_ylabel('y')
plot.set_xlabel('x')
plot.legend(title = 'Legend', loc = 'center left', bbox_to_anchor = (1.025, 0.5))
fig.savefig('plot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The output figure I get with this code:

[image]

And measuring the dimensions of the light grey area I find they are not equal.

Comment: Hmm... that plot is *not* what matplotlib looks like by default. Have you changed the settings significantly, or imported seaborn? By comparison, my installation of matplotlib with the exact same commands does create a square plot (I raised it to 6,6 rather than 3,3 to make it easier for me to see on my screen, though)

Comment: Yes it is not the default setting. I have modified the matplotlibrc file slightly, mostly colour settings.

Comment: I've had a chance to mess with this further, and I'm convinced that the problem has something to do with your modified settings. What output do you get from gca().get_position()?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you want the *physical* lengths of the axes to be equal. In this case, why aren't you just setting the figsize? Eg

```
import pylab
pylab.figure( figsize=(3,3) )
```

I should note that it appears set_aspect does nothing with semilog plots. It's not quite clear *what* it would do: the point of set_aspect is to set the aspect ratio with regards to the data scales. For example, set_aspect(1) would make 1 unit on the x axis the same size as 1 unit on the y axes. If the data scales aren't the same, then it's not clear what that aspect ratio means.

Comment: I tried but that doesn't give equal axes physical lengths.